# Dependency problem 15.10 (wily)

Tags: usb, dependencies, 15.10

I am getting following output when I do:
sudo apt-get install vlc

also I get similar type of message when I do:
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

I just freshly installed ubuntu 15.10.

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 using USB.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles2
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you run an update first?  $ sudo apt-get update

Comment: yes I did run "sudo apt-get update", but still I face above error.

Comment: it was a mirror problem, had to select some other mirror